# Pandas: how to parse values from column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, counter

I have a somewhat large dataframe, formatted something like this:

```
colA  colB
1     c, d
2     d, e, f
3     e, d, a
```

I want to get a dictionary that counts instances of unique values in colB, like:

```
a: 1
c: 1
d: 3
e: 2
f: 1
```

My naive solution would be to iterate over every row of colB, split that, then use a `Counter`: `my_counter[current_colB_object] += 1`.

However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/2143578) strongly discourages iterating over dataframes, especially (like in my case) large ones.

What would be the preferred way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `explode` and `value_counts`:

```
>>> df["colB"].str.split(", ").explode().value_counts().to_dict()
{'d': 3, 'e': 2, 'c': 1, 'f': 1, 'a': 1}
```

###### Input `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"colA": [1, 2, 3],
                   "colB": ["c, d", "d, e, f", "e, d, a"]
                   })

>>> df
   colA     colB
0     1     c, d
1     2  d, e, f
2     3  e, d, a
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably faster than the other answer -- you might want to time both yourself on a sample of your data; see `df.sample()`.

```
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter()
df.colB.str.split(', ').apply(cnt.update)
dict(cnt)
```

Outputs

```
{'c': 1, 'd': 3, 'e': 2, 'f': 1, 'a': 1}
```